# What algorithm does Qiskit use to decompose arbitrary n-qubit unitaries on Rotations + CNOT?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms

I found that Qiskit uses Unroll3qOrMore in the transpiler class function to decompose an arbitrary $n > 2$ unitary and represent it as a directed acyclic graph (DAG). But I can't find an algorithm (or paper for it). Could you help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n > 2$ qubit gates the Qiskit transpiler uses column-by-column decomposition (see: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06911.pdf).

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2WcZS4yO1Q (comment section)